# How to update first td value onclickthe way it does when dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

I have rewritten my question to better elaborate as to what I am trying to accomplish and what I have tried thus far.

I have a table on my website which dynamically loads the table rows from a database. I have successfully integrated the jQuery UI "Sortable" and "Draggable" functionality to this page. the outcome is the numeric value changes as you are dragging the rows above or below their neighboring rows and as a result always update the first column of numbers within the table.

Here is the table

```
<form action="" method="post" id="sort_picks">

 <div class="sort-picks-container">

 <table class="table-preference-order" id="sortable">
<tbody class="ui-sortable">

<?php
    $counter = 1;
    foreach ( $result as $query ){ 
        $pickcheck = "SELECT * FROM picks";
        $pickcutoffcheck = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare ($pickcheck, OBJECT_K ));
        foreach ($pickcutoffcheck as $pickcutoffresult) { ?>

        <div style="display:none;"><?php echo $pickcutoffresult->pickCutoff; ?></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php $maxlimit = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT count(*) as CNT1 FROM picks where User='$userid'"  ); ?>
      <tr class="ui-state-default preference-row">

        <td class="index preference-pick-order">
            <input type="text" class="pick-order" id="sort" name="sort[]" pattern="[1-<?php echo $maxlimit->CNT1; ?>]{1,2}" value="<?php echo $counter; ?>" style="border:0px;max-width:60px;font-size:20px;" readonly>
        </td>

        <td class="preference-pick-order">
          <input type="text" name="rem[]" class="borderless" style="text-align:left;width:25px;display:none;" value="<?php echo $query->REM; ?>" readonly><?php echo $query->REM; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="preference-emp-info">
          <input type="text" name="empname[]" class="borderless" style="display:none;" value="<?php echo $query->EmpName; ?>" readonly><b><?php echo $query->EmpName; ?></b>
        </td>
        <td class="preference-start-class">
          <input type="text" name="starttime[]" class="borderless" style="text-align:left;max-width:75px;display:none;" value="<?php echo $query->StartTime; ?>" readonly><?php echo $query->StartTime; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="preference-details">
            <input type="text" name="job_details[]" class="borderless" value="<?php echo $query->Job_Details; ?>" readonly style="display:none;"><?php echo $query->Job_Details; ?>
          <br>
                <input type="text" name="startdate[]" class="borderless" style="font-weight:bold;width:100%;text-align:left;display:none;" value="<?php if($query->StartDate!=""){echo date('l\, F jS Y', strtotime($query->StartDate)); }?>" readonly><?php if($query->StartDate!=""){echo date('l\, F jS Y', strtotime($query->StartDate)); }?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php $counter++; ?>
 <?php  }?>
      </tbody>
 </table>

 </div>
 <br>
 <div class="sorters-holder">
    <button onclick="upNdown('up');return false;" class="sorters">&wedge; </button><br>
    <button onclick="upNdown('down');return false;" class="sorters">&vee;</button>
 </div>
        <div style="display:block;margin:auto;text-align:center;">


 <input type="submit" name="submit[]" value="Next" class="job-select-submit" id="validate">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;" value="Back" class="job-select-submit">
    </div>
 </form>
```

This is the working jQuery script

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="../wp-content/themes/Excellence_At_Work/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
 var sort;
 $j(function() {
   $j("#sortable tbody").sortable({
     change: function(event, ui) {
  sort = 0;
  $j('#sortable tr.ui-state-default:not(".ui-sortable-helper")').each(function() {
    sort++;
    if ($j(this).hasClass('ui-sortable-placeholder'))
      ui.helper.find('td input[name^=sort]').attr('name', 'sort[]').attr('value', sort).val(sort);
    else
      $j(this).find('td input[name^=sort]').attr('name', 'sort[]').attr('value', sort).val(sort);
  });
     }
   });

$j("#sortable tbody").disableSelection();
 });
 </script>
 <script>jQuery('#sortable').draggable();</script>
```

As you can see in the html code, I have successfully integrated the buttons that I need to relocate the rows however when doing so I need the value of the first td to also update accordingly as does the drab and drop method. What would I add to the below javascript to get the value of the input with the name sort[] to change to its corresponding numeric place within the table rows newly changed order onclick?

```
<script>
 var order;  // variable to set the selected row index
 function getSelectedRow()
 {
    var table = document.getElementById("sortable");
    for(var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++)
    {
        table.rows[i].onclick = function()
        {
        if(typeof order !== "undefined"){
            table.rows[order].classList.toggle("selected");
        }

        order = this.rowIndex;
        this.classList.toggle("selected");

        };
    }

 }
 getSelectedRow();

 function upNdown(direction)
 {
    var rows = document.getElementById("sortable").rows,
        parent = rows[order].parentNode;
     if(direction === "up")
     {
     if(order > 0){
        parent.insertBefore(rows[order],rows[order - 1]);  
        // when the row go up the index will be equal to index - 1
        order--;
    }

 }

 if(direction === "down")
 {
     if(order < rows.length){
        parent.insertBefore(rows[order + 1],rows[order]);
        // when the row go down the index will be equal to index + 1
        order++;
    }
 }
 }
 </script>
```

I hope this better explains whatt I am trying to accomplish. I have hit a road block and could really use some insight, thanks in advance for all those who can provide insight.

**UPDATE**

I have been able to successfully update the rows first td values onclick by adding the following script after order-- and order++ however this solution is causing the input fields to drop out of the td. Any insight on how to modify this script to include the input field?

```
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('td:first-child'), function (elem, idx) {
        elem.innerHTML = idx + 1;
```

**FINAL UPDATE**

I have succeeded in my mission and with a minor adjustment to the snippet from the last update I was able to get the form above working as noted.

```
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('td:first-child input[name^=sort]'), function (elem, idx) {
    elem.value = idx + 1;
```

By changing

```
 'td:first-child'
```

to

```
'td:first-child input[name^=sort]'
```

I was able to reference the specific input field as opposed to all input fields in the first td column and no longer am replacing the input fields with plain text.

Comment: thanks Ali for fixing my typo, any insight on the issue itself by chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINAL UPDATE

I have succeeded in my mission and with a minor adjustment to the snippet from the last update I was able to get the form above working as noted.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('td:first-child input[name^=sort]'), function (elem, idx) {
elem.value = idx + 1;
```

By changing

```
'td:first-child'
```

to

```
'td:first-child input[name^=sort]'
```

I was able to reference the specific input field as opposed to all input fields in the first td column and no longer am replacing the input fields with plain text.